# filter rows for column value in list of words pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with pyspark dataframe. I have a column `words` (`array<string>`)as shown below:

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id|                                                                           words|                      
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|012|[content, type, multipart, alternative, boundaries, nextpart, nextpart, drama,..|
|013|[received, from, am5eur02ht120, eop, eur02, prod, protection, outlook by, pro...|
|014|[data, care, much, important, information, summer, care, send, faraway, forget..|
```

Also I have a list of words:

```
list = ["protection", "content", "received"]
```

I want to filter rows which have any value from the list.

Expected output:

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id|                                                                           words|                      
----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|012|[content, type, multipart, alternative, boundaries, nextpart, nextpart, drama,..|
|013|[received, from, am5eur02ht120, eop, eur02, prod, protection, outlook by, pro...|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use [array_intersect](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect) function together with [size](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) function to achieve what you need, something like this (not tested, not sure about exact code for this `F.lit(list)`):

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F

>>> df.show()
+----------------+
|           words|
+----------------+
|[content, word2]|
|      [111, 222]|
+----------------+

>>> list_col = F.array(*[F.lit(cl) for cl in list])
>>> df.filter(F.size(F.array_intersect(F.col("words"), list_col)) > 0).show()
+----------------+
|           words|
+----------------+
|[content, word2]|
+----------------+
```

Comment: thank you for looking into it. the above solution throws an error: `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: thank you for the updated solution. could you please explain what is happening in `list_col = F.array(*[F.lit(cl) for cl in list])`  ?

Comment: array_intersect function requirs two arrays as arguments. That line creates array from the list of given values